# Add active class to next child from next parent on next button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add active class to `td` tags when `click` next button and remove from current button, and also do same with pervious button

```js
// functions button
$('button:eq(0)').on('click', () => {
  if ($('.one').hasClass('activeQ')) {
    $('.one').removeClass('activeQ').next().addClass('activeQ');
    $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.activeQ').removeClass('activeQ').next('.Q').addClass('activeQ');
    $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active')

  }
});
$('button:eq(1)').on('click', function() {
  if ($('.one').hasClass('activeQ')) {

  } else {
    $('.activeQ').removeClass('activeQ').prev('.Q').addClass('activeQ');
    $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td data-class=".one" class="active">1</td>
  <td data-class=".tow">2</td>
  <td data-class=".three">3</td>
  <td data-class=".four">4</td>
  <td data-class=".five">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td data-class=".six">6</td>
  <td data-class=".seven">7</td>
  <td data-class=".eight">8</td>
  <td data-class=".nine">9</td>
  <td data-class=".ten">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: There are no buttons shown and `data-class` is not the same as `class` which you are using in selectors like `$('.one')`. Please provide a [mcve] along with an actual problem statement regarding the code shown. Also take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: iam using data-class for td click when click on any td it get showen question has same class

Comment: my problem in in thes //  $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active')

Comment: when active class reach to td number 5 and click button td number 6 not have active class beacues it child from another parent

Comment: i hope you understand me